TensorFlow Metal not installable on M2 MacBook and Github page is down
I've been attempting to install tf metal on my computer so that I can use GPUs instead of CPUs. I have tf macOS installed already, and I am fully updated with pip and tf. I'm currently 2 months into building and training a tf CNN, and I'm at the point where training a single epoch for my network will take a week (I have a lot of data that I need to use). I desperately need to use GPUs but am stuck with CPUs for now. I can't get access to a cluster, so the best I can do is continue to use my M2 MacBook. Is there a way I can work around not being able to install tf metal?
I keep getting this error message:
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-metal (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-metal"
I looked on apple forums, tried to download it from GitHub (the page is down), and anything else I could think of and/or find on the internet to help, but it still isn't installing.
I've used the following commands and still no luck:

python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
pip install https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_metal/releases/download/v0.5.0/tensorflow_metal-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
pip install tensorflow-metal
pip3 install tensorflow-metal
SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 pip install tensorflow-macos tensorflow-metal
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much!

What's your python version? The latest tensorflow-metal seems to support only python 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11. If you're using a different python version, you won't be able to get it from PyPi

@Lescurel Ah that must be the issue then, I'm using Python 3.12.4... Would you suggest I downgrade to 3.11 to try to install it that way? Thanks for the help!

Downgrading to 3.11 is probably the easiest way forward, yes.

Please answer your own question in case downgrade has resolved your issue. This is going to help the community

Nothing worked for this problem, unfortunately. I ended up using a cluster supported by my University instead.

I'm on a M1 pro and the lastest combination working is Python 3.11 with tensorflow 2.15 and tensorflow-metal 1.1.0, both installable py PyPi. It has been reported that keras 3 makes no use of the GPU (at least on macos), but I have not tested this. tensorflow 2.15 ist the last version with keras 2. If this does not work for you, it could be an issue with the M2.
